# I am getting a MemoryError in my Python program

Tags: python

I am trying to do a question that says pick combinations of 4 unique letters and tell all the possible permutations of all of them. There should be no repeating element in the answer. However, when I am trying to do it on Hackerrank, it is giving me MemoryError for strings of length greater than 23. Here is the code:

```
word = input()
answer = []
st_arr = []
for j in range(len(word) - 1, -1, -1):
    for k in range(len(st_arr)):
        # mid = word[j] + st_arr[k]
        # if len(mid) == 4:
        st_arr.append(word[j] + st_arr[k])
    st_arr.append(word[j])
for j in st_arr:
    if len(j) == 4:
        final_list = [[]]
        length = len(j)
        groups = [list(j)] * length
        for i in groups:
            final_list = [x+[y] for x in final_list for y in i]
        permutations = [''.join(item) for item in final_list]
        for i in permutations:
            x = list(set(i))
            y = list(i)
            x.sort()
            y.sort()
            if x == y:
                answer.append(i)
```

This is Python code. What should I do?

Comment: You're generating a list with all possible subsets of the given string (with exponential size), so it's unsurprising that you're getting a memory error.

Comment: Have you tried using generators instead of lists with the 'yield' keyword? Generators use way less memory because not the whole list is computed at once but only the ones you access.
Another option could be the built-in itertools module.